# How to predict monthly turning points in stock graphs?

Tags: stocks

Currently I am trying to make some capital gain from stocks, however I just want to ask for anyone experienced in the world of stocks if they have some idea or a generally accepted way of predicting the uptrend or down trend of a stock price. For example take a look at the below graph for a particular company's monthly stock price change:

[image]

This in general is an upward trend even if there are certain down trends in between. However if I take a look at an example of another company's stock price graph below:

[image]

This graph shows a downward trend followed by an upward trend which is then now followed by another downward trend.

These days I am no longer looking at the patterns of trends in the daily graph, however I try to look at the monthly data, however I have trouble seeing where the sudden change in the trend occurs.so I was wondering if there is some know how on how to predict using simple ideas, or if there are any sources which allows me to do this.

Comment: If you are looking at monthly data, you're not going to see  where the sudden change in the trend occurs because monthly data smooths out the noise.  There are numerous trend following  indicators.  If  you identify the trend and you take a position, you are simply  hoping that the trend continues.  But always remember, nothing predicts future price.

Comment: Are there any sources or studies which aim to conduct this kinda of prediction using previous known data?

Comment: There are all kinds of analyses that attempt to predict future prices.  One that I find incredibly ludicrous is Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: (Note: I am not at all experienced with stock trading)

Let's imagine someone could predict when stock prices would go up or down.

When the stock price is down, they will buy some. When the stock price is up, they will sell some. That will make the stock price go up when it's down and down when it's up.

They want to make as much money as they can, so they will buy and sell as many stocks as they can afford. Enough to make it so the price only goes up and down a tiny bit. So figuring out a pattern deletes it. The only part that's not deleted yet is the randomness.

Comment: @Bob Baerker: Throwing darts is said to work fairly well.  Even better if you have monkeys throwing the darts: https://www.forbes.com/sites/rickferri/2012/12/20/any-monkey-can-beat-the-market/#75320f8b630a

Comment: @jamesqf - When the Wall Street Journal attempted to do such testing, they used monkeys with either lower financial  IQs or poorer motor skills.  The pros modestly beat the monkeys.

Comment: @user253751 - Where your premise falls apart is "Let's imagine someone could predict when stock prices would go up or down."  Future price cannot be predicted.  If it could, Warren Buffet's money would be chump change.

Comment: @BobBaerker https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imagination

Comment: @user253751 - When you buy a car or a house or whatever, will they take **Imagination** as a down payment?

Comment: @BobBaerker You still do not understand how this works. Why don't you try to explain, to me, why future price cannot be predicted?

Comment: @user253751 - You have it all backwards.  One proves that something exists by demonstrating that it can be done.  Until then, it's a hard no.    So the onus is on you to be that single unique individual who goes where no man has gone before and discovers how to predict future prices.  The ball is in your court.  Show us the money!!!

Comment: @BobBaerker You can also prove that something does not exist by demonstrating that if it did exist, it would self-destruct. True or false?

Answer (score 5):

You can't.  Anyone that claims they can is selling snake oil.

You can achieve capital gains by investing regularly with a asset allocation you are comfortable with and letting that money "stew", or be invested for a long time.

It is far more profitable for you to earn money, at your chosen profession, so you have more money to invest.  Then, even mediocre returns, will make you pretty darn wealthy.